# Creating a SQL Server trigger from a variable doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

When I run the below code, it runs and prints the SQL output perfectly.

However the last `EXEC` statement throws an error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TRIGGER'

The code basically strings together some SQL to create a trigger for all existing tables.

When I manually take that `PRINT` output at the end and execute it in SSMS it works fine, but the `EXEC` in the code just won't run it.

```
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = ''

SELECT @sql = @sql + 'CREATE TRIGGER [tr_' + table_name +'] ON 
[' + table_schema + '].[' + table_name + '] FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS
SELECT 1 GO' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'

PRINT @sql; -- output is correct and I can paste this and it works
EXEC sp_executesql @sql -- doesn't work
```

Comment: You could try to replace the `GO` with a semicolon (surrounded by a space before and after) ` ; ` and see if that works

Comment: Ok I'll bite and ask the big white elephant in the room. Why are you adding a trigger to every single table in your database? Triggers should be used very sparingly, like a few in your entire career.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL command to execute has to be a single batch. So, you can't use `GO`.

You better declare a `CURSOR` and execute the script for each table.